# Suppose $2+7i$ is a solution of $2z^2+Az+B=0$, where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ . Find $A$ and $B$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is as follows;

> Suppose  $2+7i$  is a solution of  $2z^2+Az+B=0$, where  $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ . Find $A$ and $B$.

My understanding is that this equation holds:

$$2(2+7i)^2 + A(2+7i) + B = 0$$

which will eventually lead to:

$$-90 + 2A + B + i(56+7A) = 0$$

I would like to check if my approach is correct, and if so, what should I do next to derive $A$ & $B$.

Comment: If $A,B\in\mathbb R$, then $\overline z=2-7i$. Finally, you can apply Vieta's formula.

Comment: you can realize that $0 = 0 + 0i$, equating the real and imaginary parts you get a system of equations in the unknowns $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @colver, solved it ! I was so focused on solving the real equation that i didn't realise i could solve for Imaginary part thus leading to the real part. Thank you!

Comment: An approach by Lalit Tolani: since $A,B$ are real, the roots must come in conjugate pairs, or that $-\frac{A}{2} = (2 + 7i) + (2 - 7i), \frac{B}{2} = (2 + 7i)(2 - 7i)$ from Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 3):

$−90+2A+B+i(56+7A)=0$

Since $0 + 0i = 0$,

we can equate the following.

$i(56 + 7A) = 0$

$7A = -56$, thus $A = -8$

Sub A into the Real Part of the equation to get B.

Real part of the equation $-90+2(A)+B=0$

You should derive 106 for B.

Huge thanks to Colver for the heads up!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the question gives hint :

If $A$ and $B$ are real, then complex roots occur in conjugate pairs, therefore If one root is $2+7i$ other will be $2-7i$.

Now Sum of roots , $-\frac{A}{2}=4\implies A=-8$

Product of roots , $\frac{B}{2}=4+49\implies B=106 $

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial with real coefficients will have non-real roots in conjugate pairs. Since it has $2+7i$ as a root, it will also have $2-7i$ as a root. Being a degree $2$ polynomial, these are the only roots. The leading coefficient of $2z^2+Az+B=0$ is $2$, so our polynomial is:
$$2(z- (2-7i))(z -(2+7i)) = 0$$
Expanding, the coefficients we obtain:
$$2 z^2 - 2(2-7i + 2+7i)z + 2(2-7i)(2+7i)  = 0\\
2z^2 - 8z + 106 = 0$$
We get:  $A=-8$, $B = 106$.